# HTML <picture> element doesn't work in Chrome 42

Tags: image, google-chrome, responsive-design

Here is my `<picture>` element on page:

```
<picture>
     <source media="(max-width: 6400px)" srcset="./images/large.jpg 1024w"  sizes="100vw" />
</picture>
```

But when I open my page in Chrome browser, I can't see any picture. Even no image is requested in devtools network panel.

I checked [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture), that the Chrome 42 is support `<picture>` element.

So why the `<picture>` does't work?

Comment: If I'm interpreting [this spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element) correctly, you still need an `<img>` inside of `<picture>`.  The `<source>` elements just lets it choose from a list of image URLs instead of just a single one.

Answer (score 1):

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=picture), `<picture>` support is conditional on enabling `experimental Web Platform features` in chrome://flags

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `<img>` inside `<picture>`. Change your HTML to:

```
<picture>
   <source media="(max-width: 6400px)" 
           srcset="./images/large.jpg 1024w" sizes="100vw" />
   <img src="default.jpg" alt="my images" />
</picture>
```